# Renaming file based on a value in a tsv file

Tags: bash, csv

My input is a tsv file with 5 columns. It has the column names 'Position' 'A', 'B' and so on, that repeat every now and then in the tsv. How can I split this tsv file so that each one has one set of the column headers and the data underneth, but not the next set of column headers.

Input:

```
Position    A   B   C   D   Seg2
1   9   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   16  0   0
3   0   19  0   0   0
4   0   0   18  0   0
Position    A   B   C   D   Seg1
1   9   0   0   0   1
2   0   0   22  0   0
3   0   19  0   0   0
4   0   0   19  0   0
5   39  0   0   0   0
6   43  0   0   0   0
```

The ideal output would be the above in split into two tsv files, one named Seg1.tsv and the other Seg2.tsv.

What I have:

```
awk '/Position/{x="F"++i;}{print > x;}' file.tsv
```

How can I modify the above to rename the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just derive the filename from the last column :

```
awk '/Position/{x=$6".tsv"}{print > x;}' file.tsv
```